# Android SearchView issue: ListView not visible

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-fragments

I have an `ActivityA` that extends an `ActionBarActivity` in Android 4.4.2 (my project `minSdkVersion` is 14, `maxSdkVersion` is 20). In `onCreate ()` method of `ActivityA`, I start `MyMainFragment` which consumes the whole content frame that `ActivityA` owns. That is, the fragment was started like so:

```
    Fragment myMainFragment = new MyMainFragment ();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager ();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction ()
            .addToBackStack ("MyMainFragment")
            .replace (R.id.post_login_content_frame, myMainFragment)
            .commit ();
```

I have a `SearchView` in `ActivityA` that I use in my app. For my `SearchView` workflow, I capture the query entered (successfully implemented), pass it on to the fragment `MyMainFragment` which pulls data from a remote server and builds the data for a custom adapter (all implementations successful). The part I have trouble with is the actual displaying of this `ListView` data from the search. My specific problem is that the view for the `ListView` is not shown. (i.e., `view.isShown () == false` in `SearchResultsFragment.onCreateView ()` which sets up the adapter for the `ListView`--see below).

I have a custom base adapter, `SearchResultsAdapter extends BaseAdapter` that consumes `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` and presents it in a `ListView`. I know the code there works because I have successfully used it for another list in the same project.

The `myMainFragment` object started immediately after `ActivityA` starts (see above) does fill up `R.id.post_login_content_frame` with the view from `com.sonny.customView` (see xml below), and I am puzzled why `replace`ing the same with `SearchResultsFragment` won't make its `view.isShown () == true`.

Any help is deeply appreciated. I have already tried `notifyDataSetChanged ()`.

Here are the xml files (`activity_main.xml`):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/post_login_drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/post_login_content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/post_login_left_drawer"
          android:layout_width="240dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="start"
          android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
          android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
          android:dividerHeight="0dp"
          android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`fragment_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.sonny.customView
 ....
</com.sonny.customView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`person_search_results.xml` (the layout for `SearchResultsFragment.java`):

```
<ListView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/personSearchResultsLV">
</ListView>
```

and finally, the actual list row content layout, `single_search_result.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/personSearchResultPersonNameTextView" android:layout_column="0" android:layout_weight="1"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/personSearchResultUsernameTextView" android:layout_column="0"/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: So let me get this clear, you're saying `ListView android:id="@+id/post_login_left_drawer"` doesn't show up?

Comment: No, the other list view `personSearchResultsLV`.

Comment: Nobody's had this issue? Really?